# Export org agenda views periodically in Emacs

Tags: emacs, cron, org-mode, timer

To export org agenda views in a text file for further processing, I run `(org-batch-store-agenda-views)` periodically as an Emacs batch job run by cron. Because there is some overhead in starting an emacs instance to do one 500-ms function call, I wish to have one of my constantly running instances do it for me.

There is a [Timers library](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Timers.html) in Emacs but the functions provided don't call the function as desired:

```
(run-with-idle-timer 2 1 'org-batch-store-agenda-views)

(run-at-time 5 5 'org-batch-store-agenda-views)
```

What's the way to make it work? The final goal is to plant something like this in my `.emacs` init (doesn't work either):

```
  (let ((time-interval (* 60 10)))
    (defvar my-org-agenda-updater-handle
      (run-with-timer (random time-interval) time-interval
                      'org-batch-store-agenda-views)
      "A timer object that denotes our running batch job."))
```

Comment: Can you explain why you believe it is not working. I created a simple function `(defun foo () (message "GO"))` and then executed `(run-at-time 5 5 'foo)` and saw the messages appearing in the `*Messages*` buffer until I canceled the timer.

Comment: @verdammelt: Simple, really. `'org-batch-store-agenda-views` writes an ASCII agenda into a file (same stuff as `C-c a e`) and it doesn't write the file when I make the timer run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, while debugging this I made a dead simple wrap around the function and it started working. Probably the timer passes the function something funny in arguments or the closure wasn't right. In any event. :)

```
(defun progo-run-agenda-store ()
  ""
  (message "Agenda to be exported... ")
  (org-batch-store-agenda-views)
  (message "Agenda exported!"))

(run-at-time 5 5 'progo-run-agenda-store)
```